After Spring boot 3.2.x upgrade , ZoneddateTime is getting persisted in DB always with UTC format
Working scenario:
Service-A : with Java 8 , Spring boot 2.7.x

Setting the ZoneddateTime ("America/New_York") in java object and adding
it in RabbitMQ queue.

Service-B : with Java 8 , Spring boot 2.7.9

Receives the ZoneddateTime from Queue and persisting it in MySql DB.
ZoneddateTime is persisted in EST/EDT format as expected.

Mysql DB:

Result of the query (SELECT @@system_time_zone;) is EDT.
data type column in MySQL store the ZoneddateTime is - datetime

Issue:
After upgrading the Service-B (service which persist the date time in DB) to Java 17 & Spring boot 3.2.9. ZoneddateTime is getting persisted UTC format (EDT + 4 hrs)
Debugging :

I tried to convert the time to EDT/EST and then persist in DB. But still its storing it in UTC format only.


final ZonedDateTime inboundTimeEST = inboundTime.withZoneSameInstant("America/New_York");
obj.setRequestTime(inboundTimeEST);
obj.setMyJson(XXX().getBytes()); // Json in bytes
logsRepository.save(obj);


obj is from our entity class. Data type of the request time is ZonedDateTime. imported these two packages import jakarta.persistence.*;import java.time.ZonedDateTime; in our class

I downgraded the spring boot version to 2.7.9 with Java 17. the ZoneddateTime is persisted in EST/EDT format as expected. So the issue is not due to the Java upgrade i guess.

Any recommendations or suggestion to fix this issue or to debug it further? I am expecting the datetime should be in EDT/EST format.

Who is the exact data type of your column in MySQL?

ZonedDateTime is not mapped in JDBC to any data type in SQL. (Nor Instant). A moment exchanged with a SQL database must be OffsetDateTime.

@BasilBourque data type in MySQL is - datetime

What type (fq package name please) is obj?

@g00se  obj is from our entity classs. Data type of the  request time is ZonedDateTime. imported these two packages import jakarta.persistence.*;import java.time.ZonedDateTime; in our class

If you're working with ZonedDateTime I'd be very tempted to use a blob type field. If you can map to Object that way, whatever ZonedDateTime goes in, should come out

I don't really mean map to Object but rather mean that under the covers setObject would occur with the jdbc and serialisation of ZonedDateTime would happen

Post details as edits to your Question, not as Comments.

fwiw, the pain of this kind of approach might be worth the gain of being able to use your most info-rich and rational ZonedDateTime without the fear of your db messing with it. It works well for me: try (ByteArrayOutputStream bOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();PreparedStatement psIn = con.prepareStatement("insert into Date_Stuff (zdatetime) values (?)");ObjectOutputStream oOut = new ObjectOutputStream(bOut)) {oOut.writeObject(ZonedDateTime.now());psIn.setBytes(1, bOut.toByteArray());int result = psIn.executeUpdate();System.out.printf("Result value of insert was %d%n", result);}

Of course, you're not doing direct jdbc, but I thought I'd show proof of concept of the underlying idea

Thanks @everyone for your support. Finally i found the fix, posted the same in the Answer section.

This issue is due to the change in Hibernate 6.x behavior.
Spring Boot 2.x uses Hibernate 5.x , but the Spring Boot 3.x uses Hibernate 6.x.
In Hibernate 5, time zones were not stored, but normalized to the time zone set in hibernate.jdbc.time_zone / JVM time zone by default. But in Hibernate 6.x, date/time values are normalized to UTC.
More details are available in the Hibernate Migration guide
So, Setting the configuration property hibernate.timezone.default_storage to NORMALIZE reverts to the Hibernate 5’s behavior.
